# How to update a row based on changes in another row?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

Say I have two tables to keep track of a bank account:

```
Account:
------------------------------
AccountID| Account Value
------------------------------
| 0      | 1000

Transactions:
------------------------------------------------
TransactionID| Transaction Value| Paying Account
-------------------------------------------------    
| 23         | -50.0            | 0
--------------------------------------------------
| 24         | -5               | 0
```

There is an update on TransactionID=24, and the new value is say -10. 
What would the best way to update the value of the account to reflect this change?

What I've done in my code is to

1. After someone clicks ok in the edit dialog
2. Reverse the original transaction by adding the negative of the value:
3. And then apply the new transaction value to the account

   ```java
   AccountDAO acc = mDatabase.AccountDAO().getAccount(0);
   acc.account_value += transaction_id_24.value * -1;
   acc.account_value += transaction_id_24_updated.value;
   mDatabase.AccountDAO().updateAccount(acc);
   ```

   The above method works, but I feel like there is a better more automated method to the above.

Is there any way for the database to automatically detect that the value of a transaction has been changed and then update the corresponding account in sqlite/android-room?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Room has all the tools you need for this built in:

> Use LiveData with Room
>
> The Room persistence library supports observable queries, which return LiveData objects. Observable queries are written as part of a Database Access Object (DAO).
>
> Room generates all the necessary code to update the LiveData object when a database is updated. The generated code runs the query asynchronously on a background thread when needed. This pattern is useful for keeping the data displayed in a UI in sync with the data stored in a database. You can read more about Room and DAOs in the Room persistent library guide.

Simply observe the LiveData returned from you @Query in Room, and you can execute additional logic with the result returned.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical use case of a trigger.
Hope this example helps.

```
-- Standalone example

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Account;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Transactions;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trans_trigger;

create table Account (
   AccountID      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
   AccountValue   REAL            NOT NULL
);
create table Transactions (
   TransactionsID      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
   TransactionValue    REAL  NOT NULL,
   AccountID           INT   NOT NULL
);

-- Initialize data.
INSERT INTO ACCOUNT (AccountValue, AccountID) VALUES (1000, 0);
INSERT INTO Transactions (TransactionsID, TransactionValue, AccountID) VALUES (23, -50, 0);
INSERT INTO Transactions (TransactionsID, TransactionValue, AccountID) VALUES (24, -5, 0);

CREATE TRIGGER 
    trans_trig 
AFTER UPDATE OF 
    TransactionValue
ON 
    Transactions
BEGIN
    -- Remove old transaction and add new.
    UPDATE Account SET AccountValue = AccountValue - old.TransactionValue;
    UPDATE Account SET AccountValue = AccountValue + new.TransactionValue;
END;

select * from Account;
/* AccountID | AccountValue
   0         | 1000         */
UPDATE Transactions SET TransactionValue = -10 WHERE TransactionsID = 24;
select * from Account;
/* AccountID | AccountValue
   0         | 995          */
UPDATE Transactions SET TransactionValue = 50 WHERE TransactionsID = 24;
select * from Account;
/* AccountID | AccountValue
   0         | 1055         */
```